# Progressive concatenation of a column by a group

Tags: r, string, aggregation

Suppose that I have this input :

```
             ID     date_1      date_2     str
1            1    2010-07-04  2008-01-20   A
2            2    2015-07-01  2011-08-31   C
3            3    2015-03-06  2013-01-18   D
4            4    2013-01-10  2011-08-30   D
5            5    2014-06-04  2011-09-18   B
6            5    2014-06-04  2011-09-18   B
7            6    2012-11-22  2011-09-28   C
8            7    2014-06-17  2013-08-04   A
10           7    2014-06-17  2013-08-04   B
11           7    2014-06-17  2013-08-04   B
```

I would like to progressively concatenate the values of the `str` column by the group variable `ID`, as showed in the following output :

```
             ID     date_1      date_2     str
1            1    2010-07-04  2008-01-20   A
2            2    2015-07-01  2011-08-31   C
3            3    2015-03-06  2013-01-18   D
4            4    2013-01-10  2011-08-30   D
5            5    2014-06-04  2011-09-18   B
6            5    2014-06-04  2011-09-18   B,B
7            6    2012-11-22  2011-09-28   C
8            7    2014-06-17  2013-08-04   A
10           7    2014-06-17  2013-08-04   A,B
11           7    2014-06-17  2013-08-04   A,B,B
```

I tried to use the `ave()` function with this code :

```
within(table, {
  Emp_list <- ave(str, ID, FUN = function(x) paste(x, collapse = ","))
})
```

but it gives the following output, which is not exactly what I want :

```
         ID      date_1     date_2      str
1         1    2010-07-04 2008-01-20     A
2         2    2015-07-01 2011-08-31     C
3         3    2015-03-06 2013-01-18     D
4         4    2013-01-10 2011-08-30     D
5         5    2014-06-04 2011-09-18     B,B
6         5    2014-06-04 2011-09-18     B,B
7         6    2012-11-22 2011-09-28     C
8         7    2014-06-17 2013-08-04     A,B,B
10        7    2014-06-17 2013-08-04     A,B,B
11        7    2014-06-17 2013-08-04     A,B,B
```

Of course I'd like to avoid loops, as I work on a large database.

Comment: I am afraid you have to use loop in this case, since this is a sequential problem

Comment: Liam, I would recommend you accept an answer to this question and then ask a new question instead of adding more to this one.

Answer (score 9):

How about `ave()` with `Reduce()`.  The `Reduce()` function allows us to accumulate results as they are calculated.  So if we run it with `paste()` we can accumulate the pasted strings.

```
f <- function(x) {
    Reduce(function(...) paste(..., sep = ", "), x, accumulate = TRUE)
}

df$str <- with(df, ave(as.character(str), ID, FUN = f)
```

which gives the updated data frame `df`

```
   ID     date_1     date_2     str
1   1 2010-07-04 2008-01-20       A
2   2 2015-07-01 2011-08-31       C
3   3 2015-03-06 2013-01-18       D
4   4 2013-01-10 2011-08-30       D
5   5 2014-06-04 2011-09-18       B
6   5 2014-06-04 2011-09-18    B, B
7   6 2012-11-22 2011-09-28       C
8   7 2014-06-17 2013-08-04       A
10  7 2014-06-17 2013-08-04    A, B
11  7 2014-06-17 2013-08-04 A, B, B
```

**Note:** `function(...) paste(..., sep = ", ")` could also be `function(x, y) paste(x, y, sep = ", ")`.  (Thanks Pierre Lafortune)

Comment: Dammit, beat me to it as I was trying to figure out the `...` in the `paste` function. Nicely done.

Comment: Haha, you beat me as well with the `Reduce` part. ;)

Comment: @RichardScriven - `Reduce` needs a binary (or binary compatible) function like `+` etc to work properly.  Using `...` allows this to happen with `paste`, otherwise it screws up using just `function(x) paste(x,sep=",")` as two arguments are expected by `Reduce`.

Comment: @RichardScriven - I know you have - I was just explaining that `function(...)` is necessary instead of the possibly more obvious `function(x)` - you said you were figuring out how to explain it so I thought I'd chime in.

Comment: Nicely done ! that's exactly what I wanted :) Thanks @RichardScriven

Comment: You don't need the dots for it to work, `function(x,y) paste(x,y, sep=", ")` should work just fine

Comment: @PierreLafortune - true, you could make it a binary function explicitly too.

Answer (score 8):

Here's a possible solution combining `data.table` with an inner `tapply` that seem to get you what you need (you can use `paste` instead of `toString` if you like, it just looks cleaner to me that way).

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[, Str := tapply(str[sequence(1:.N)], rep(1:.N, 1:.N), toString), by = ID]
df
#     ID     date_1     date_2 str     Str
#  1:  1 2010-07-04 2008-01-20   A       A
#  2:  2 2015-07-01 2011-08-31   C       C
#  3:  3 2015-03-06 2013-01-18   D       D
#  4:  4 2013-01-10 2011-08-30   D       D
#  5:  5 2014-06-04 2011-09-18   B       B
#  6:  5 2014-06-04 2011-09-18   B    B, B
#  7:  6 2012-11-22 2011-09-28   C       C
#  8:  7 2014-06-17 2013-08-04   A       A
#  9:  7 2014-06-17 2013-08-04   B    A, B
# 10:  7 2014-06-17 2013-08-04   B A, B, B
```

You may be able to improve it a bit using

```
setDT(df)[, Str := {Len <- 1:.N ; tapply(str[sequence(Len)], rep(Len, Len), toString)}, by = ID]
```

Comment: This looks nice and should not take too long on large datasets, thank you !