# Equivalent to cumsum for string in R

Tags: r

I am looking for a way to do what would be the equivalent of a cumulative sum in R for string/character-formatted text instead of numbers. The different text fields should be concatenated.

E.g. in the data frame "df":

Column A contains the input, column B the desired result.

```
  A        B
1 banana   banana 
2 boats    banana boats
3 are      banana boats are
4 awesome  banana boats are awesome
```

Currently I am solving this via the following loop

```
df$B <- ""

for(i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if (length(df[i-1,"A"]) > 0) {
        df$B[i] <- paste(df$B[i-1],df$A[i])
    } else {
        df$B[i] <- df$A[i]
    }
}
```

I wonder whether there exists a more elegant/faster solution.

Comment: It is not at all "cumsum"!

Comment: Is performance an issue?

Comment: I _think_ the classic `cumpaste` appeared [**here**](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24862046/cumulative-pasting-concatenating-values-grouped-by-another-variable-in-r/24864007#24864007) first (possible duplicate). Cudos to @alexis_laz.

Comment: [Another similar Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34778422/progressive-concatenation-of-a-column-by-a-group?lq=1), albeit also 'by group' like the answer above. But the 'by group' is rarely the tricky part...

Comment: Thanks for all the answers! Found Reduce to be the fastest so marked that as top answer. Sorry in case this was a duplicate! It appears I searched for the wrong terms.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
(df$B <- Reduce(paste, as.character(df$A), accumulate = TRUE))
# [1] "banana"     "banana boats"      "banana boats are"    "banana boats are awesome"
```

Comment: Impressive, and blazingly fast. (on an input vector of 1000 strings, 20x faster than my solution)

Comment: @Heroka Reduce is just a `for` loop.

Comment: @Roland and so is sapply, but on my machine `Reduce` blew the other answers out of the park. I think it's the `accumulate = TRUE`.

Comment: @Heroka Well, yes. Obviously it handles the accumulation better than your approach, but it's just nice syntactic sugar. If you look at the internal code you see a standard `for` loop.

Comment: TIL, thanks. Still reduce is faster, or I wrote an inefficient for-loop.

Comment: @Roland it's not "just" a for loop. There's quite a lot more going on that explains the increase in speed. For a start, you have forced calls (see `?forceAndCall`. And more importantly, the function `Reduce` is compiled to bytecode already. Any compiled code will outperform a "hand made" for-loop. So calling it syntactic sugar is doing injustice to the function.

Comment: @JorisMeys I have no issue with `Reduce`. I use it myself. But it is "just a `for` loop", though a well written one. You can byte-compile a `for` loop yourself and better performance is likely.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's faster, but at least the code is shorter:

```
sapply(seq_along(df$A),function(x){paste(A[1:x], collapse=" ")})
```

Thanks to Rolands comment, I realised that this was one of the rare occurences where a for-loop could be useful, as it saves us the repeated indexing. It differs from OP's as it starts at 2, saving the need for the if statment inside the forloop.

```
res <- c(NA, length(df1$A))
res[1] <- as.character(df1$A[1])
for(i in 2:length(df1$A)){
   res[i] <- paste(res[i-1],df1$A[i])
 }
res
```

Answer (score 4):

We can try

```
 i1 <- sequence(seq_len(nrow(df1)))
 tapply(df1$A[i1], cumsum(c(TRUE,diff(i1) <=0)),
                     FUN= paste, collapse=' ')
```

---

Or

```
 i1 <- rep(seq(nrow(df1)), seq(nrow(df1)))
 tapply(i1, i1, FUN= function(x) 
          paste(df1$A[seq_along(x)], collapse=' ') )
```